# How does iphone Notifications on Websites works? Is need to install Application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have problem with understand how "Push Notifications on Websites" works on Iphone, Ipad, etc.

Default Browser Notifications don't work on mobile, but this: `https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html`
should be work fine!

There is good documentation how to install it, but how it works on user?
As i see, it`s 2 variants:

1) Modal Window to allow using notifications in browser like it`s working with default JS Notifications. 
or:
2) Link to install application in AppStore. So, user install to device application.

So, if user download application, does this application add to desktop on device as other applications? What happing when user click on icon? Does click on application on desktop activate safari and open web-site? Or is it hidden application without icons on desktop?

I try to find some sites to check examples how it will work with my iphone, but i didnt find any sites. All popular sites say: "download application and active notifications THERE and use application for website".

So, i don't need special application for my site, adaptive design is awesome for me, but i want to use notifications on iphone!

Please, help me :) Thank you!

Comment: As the documentation you linked to says, website notifications are only for macOS. If you have an account system and the user logs in to your website and your app then you can correlate the device with the users account and push notications to the app.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed the document states that this feature is available on OSX not on iPad, iPhone. 
We see this notifications when we open a website on Safari. For instance,

[image: Pinterest push notification]

As soon as we click the allow button, our Macbook communicates with Apple Push Notification Service to establish a persistent IP connection (along with a token exchange). When the website servers send notifications to the Apple Push Notification Service it forwards that notification to our Macbook/iMac.